# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Flex operation projects/.../regions/us-central1/operations/... error [FAILED_PRECONDITION]

Tags: gcloud, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible, streamlit

I'm pretty new on Google Cloud, and I just wanted to deploy my first streamlit webapp. I'm on Windows in command line. I already did the Google Cloud "Hello World" Example, which worked without any error.

When I deploy the streamlit webapp, I got after 3-4 minutes waiting "Updating Server" the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Flex operation projects/XXXX/regions/us-central1/operations/f0c89d22-2d09-410d-bf99-fc49ad337800 error [FAILED_PRECONDITION]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2021-05-27T06:13:50.278Z10796.jc.0: 2021-05-27 06:15:32.787 An update to the [server] config option section was detected. To have these changes be reflected, please restart streamlit.
```

That's my app.yaml file:

```
service: default
runtime: custom
env: flex
manual_scaling: 
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Comment: I followed an example published in this [medium article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-streamlit-apps-to-google-app-engine-in-5-simple-steps-5e2e2bd5b172) and couldn't reproduce this error. 

Try deploying your app after updating the gcloud with `gcloud components update`.  Also, make sure you run the SDK as an Admin.

If the error recurs, run the `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=debug` to try getting more specified error.

Comment: Thanks, I had a mistake in my Dockerfile.
Now I don't get the error anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer for better visibility and to summarize.

In this particular case, the error was caused by a mistake in the Dockerfile.

Here are some steps you can follow to fix or narrow down the error:

- Try to deploy a test app to see the differences in configuration. [Example](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-streamlit-apps-to-google-app-engine-in-5-simple-steps-5e2e2bd5b172).
- Try deploying your app after updating the gcloud with `gcloud components update` command.
- Make sure you run the SDK as an Admin.
- If the error recurs, run the `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=debug` to try getting more specified error.